# Querying BigQuery's INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES from dataflow results in error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA to retrieve metadata about bigquery tables from dataflow. Find the code and the error below. The same query is working fine from the BQ UI

```
query=SELECT * EXCEPT(is_typed) FROM `dummy_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`"

p1=p | "create1" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))

"errors": [
      {
        "message": "Illegal operation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA view: dummy_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) and include a job ID if possible, since that will have more details that enable BigQuery's engineering team to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view from my dataset by using the runner `DataflowRunner`, but I got the same error message as you when I used `DirectRunner`. Thus, like [Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253347/elliott-brossard) mentions, you could file a bug for the BigQuery team, as well for the [Dataflow team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1162867). In the meantime, you could try using `DataflowRunner` to read from this view.

Hope it helps.